# Auto fill field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

in account.analytic.lines i have field number. every project have the numer field.
So y goal is to auto fill project_id field that is in lines when i type in number field in lines.

```py
class AccountAnalyticLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.analytic.line'

    number = fields.Integer(related='project_id.number',string='Project Number')

    @api.onchange('number')
    def get_project_id(self):
        v={}
        if self.number:
            project = self.env['project.project']
            if project.project_id.id:
                v['project'] = project.project_id and project.project_id.id or False
        return {'value': v}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
 @api.onchange('number')
 def get_project_id(self):
    # in new api no need for return and you can
    # affect change directly to self
    project = false
    if self.number:
        project_obj = self.env['project.project']
        # now search for project that have the same number
        porject = project_obj.search([('number', '=', self.number)], limit=1)

    self.project_id = project
    # if you want to show a warning when user fillup
    # the number field and there is no project found
    if not self.project_id and self.number:
        # number is not empty but there is no project with this number
        return {'warning': {
                        'title': _("Project Warning"),
                        'message': _('No project found with this number : %s ') % self.number
                    }}
```

don't forget to import the translation toos:

```
# 10.0
from odoo.tools.translate import _
```

Comment: check my edit you may want to add a warning message for your user